# Proving that a variety has a lower dimension than its ambient space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, krull-dimension, transcendence-degree

I want to prove the following :

Let $V$ be an irreducible affine variety in $\mathbb{A}^n$ with $V \not=\mathbb{A}^n $. Then $dimV < n$.

I tried to prove this by contradiction but my proof doesn't work. I thought my choice of $y_i$ was enough to garantee algebraic independence but it isn't. Can someone help me modify my proof ?

This is what I tried so far:

---

Suppose $dimV \geq n$. Then there exists a strictly increasing chain of irreducible subvarieties of $V$
$$V_0 \varsubsetneq ... \varsubsetneq V_n \subset V \varsubsetneq \mathbb{A}^n$$
and a corresponding decreasing chain of prime ideals in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]$
$$I_0 \varsupsetneq ... \varsupsetneq I_n \supset I \varsupsetneq (0) $$
with $I_i = I(V_i)$ and $I = I(V)$.
Now we choose any $y_n \in I_n \setminus (0)$ and for all the other $I_i$ choose a $y_i \in I_i\setminus (y_n,...,y_{i+1})$. By construction all the $\{y_0,...,y_n\}$ are $n+1$ independent elements of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]$ which is impossible.

Comment: You have shown the statement in the title, that the dimension of $\Bbb{A}^n$ is at least one more than that of $V$. Then $\dim\Bbb{A}^n=n$ because by induction there are some $e_j$ such that $\mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]/I_m$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{C}[x_{e_1},...,x_{e_{n-m}}]/(\mathbb{C}[x_{e_1},...,x_{e_{n-m}}]\cap I_m)$ , thus $\mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]/I_n$ is algebraic over $\Bbb{C}$, and since it is finitely generated it has to be $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: How can I see that $\mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]/I_m$  is algebraic over $\mathbb{C}[x_{e_1},...,x_{e_{n−m}}]/(\mathbb{C}[x_{e_1},...,x_{e_{n−m}}]∩I_m)$ ?